# How to create multiple subelements (having children) from a dataframe under a single root in XML using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a tree whose Subelement has multiple categories which further has the children. The Subelement of same type but different categories should lie under the same root.

Expected:

[image]

I know there should be a loop in the working so that the same line of code for different categories would run over those lines to append under the same root but having a hard time figuring it.

My code is below

This only generates different roots instead.

```
for i in range(len(df["animalId"])):
    category = df[i][0]
    name = df[i][1]
    legs = df[i][2]
    type = df[i][3]

    animals = etree.Element("animals")
    etree.SubElement(animals, "category").text = str(category)
    etree.SubElement(category, "version").text = str(version)
    etree.SubElement(version, "name").text = str(name)
    etree.SubElement(version, "legs").text = str(legs)
    etree.SubElement(version, "type").text = str(type)

    xmlstr =  minidom.parseString(etree.toString(animals)).toprettyxml(indent = "   ")
    print (xmlstr)
```

Resulting:

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please help on this?